# RegEx not correctly capturing data

Tags: c#, .net, regex

So I have the following code.

```
var filter = new Regex("(?<=description=\\\")(.+)(?=\\\">)");            
return filter.Match(html).ToString();
```

The HTML data that regex is applied to:

```
<description="This chapter builds upon the information in part 1 ("Introduction to Dynamic Equations")">
```

The result:

> This Chapter builds upon the Information in part 1 (" Introduction="" to="" Dynamic="" Equations="" ")

It seems that after the ' (" ' the regex tries to create key value pairs. I've tried all the RegexOptions, but none of the options change the behavior.

Comment: `(` [anything] `)` makes a backreference to \1-\n, Let me know what you need help with more than the below

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "tries to create key value pairs"? The regex seems to be working as intended to me. See [this ideone](http://ideone.com/YazHad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### DEMO: [regex101](http://www.regex101.com/r/fU7cF1)

**REGEX**

```
<description="(.+)">
```

Description

```
<description=" Literal <description="
1st Capturing group (.+) 
    . 1 to infinite times [greedy] Any character (except newline)
"> Literal ">
```

Test String:

```
<description="This chapter builds upon the information in part 1 ("Introduction to Dynamic Equations")">
```

> 1. [14-102] `This chapter builds upon the information in part 1 ("Introduction to Dynamic Equations")`